# CSS Price Format: Magento1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, price, css

Design of website requires the final price on product view page to be formatted as below

[image]

In order to do this we need to have html like

```
<span class="dollar">$</span><span>499</span><span class="decimal">00</span>
```

By extending formatCurrency function we can add extra span, but what about price change on selecting custom options?

Is there any other way to do this only with CSS?

Comment: this might help you - https://www.ubertheme.com/question/separate-the-decimal-part-of-the-price-layout/

Comment: Have you tried the standard HTML tag `<sup>`? https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_sup.asp

Comment: This works fine, But format is lost when any custom options is selected since old Price is replaced by New one.